# Convert docx to pdf on django

Tags: python, django

I want convert a docx file to pdf in django. I use `from docx2pdf import convert` function to convert my file. I add `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` to my code and it works well on my local environment. But in my cpanel environment `import pythoncom` and structure `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`  do not define and it has error.
please help me to make pdf file at cpanel environment.

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
doc = DocxTemplate("f.docx")
context = {'company_name': "lllll"}
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
convert('generated_doc.docx')
```

Comment: On Cpanel did you install docx2pdf ??

Comment: Are you sure that you need `pythoncom` at all?

Comment: In windows os it solves my problem. But in Linux it does not work. How can convert my docx file to pdf in Linux python?

Comment: Yes I installed docx2pdf